# Adding set of fields to form dynamically by click and retrieve information

Tags: java, android

I have registration form in my application which has button to basically duplicate fields for another additional user(kid):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/registration_label" />

<!---->


<!--Not related  code-->


<!---->
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_child_last_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/child_last_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_white_24px"
            android:hint="@string/last_name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_dob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dob"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_calendar"
            android:hint="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:inputType="date" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_reg_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_white_24px"
            android:hint="@string/login" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_reg_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_enhanced_encryption_white_24px"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/add_kids"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48px"
                    app:fabSize="mini" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:text="@string/add_kids" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_registration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                android:text="@string/send" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

So, when user clicks on FAB, additional fields must be shown. As I understood it can be done by using `inflater`(inflate from other xml file) or by `ListView`. Which approach is better. And what is important how to retrieve data from new fields and validate their presence?